# upgraded from 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 but kernel didn't change how to fix

Tags: 16.04, kernel, 18.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu 16.04 64bit machine to 18.04 but when I do a uname -sr  it shows the old kernel of 4.4.127-0404127 #201804081036

I know the kernel should be 4.15 how can I fix this so the kernel gets upgraded corectly?

Comment: This is odd. The current kernel in 16.04 is 4.4.0-122-generic. You need to post more info about the hardware in question, the output of `uname -a`, then may be, we can help.

Answer (score 2):

I ran the command below to unhold the kernel but it didn't work.

```
sudo apt-mark unhold linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
```

But when I ran the command below it download and upgraded my kernel.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt install linux-image-generic
```

And to check it I used

```
uname -sr
```

Linux 4.15.0-20-generic

Success.

On a side note everything was really slow I also had some old KDE files that were causing problems and had to run

```
balooctl disable
```

For more information about it here's a link

[permanently disable the baloo file indexer](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193169)